# Why is urllib.request.urlopen giving me 404 on Wall Street Journal's website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-status-code-404, urllib

**Problem**

I'm using `urllib.request.urlopen` on the Wall Street Journal and it gives me a 404.

**Details**

Other sites work fine. Same error if I use `https://`. I did this example in REPL but the same error happens in my calls from my Django server:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> urlopen('http://www.wsj.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

This is how it should work:

```
>>> urlopen('http://www.cbc.ca')
<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x10b0f8c88>
```

I'm not sure how to debug this. Anyone know what's going on, and how I can fix it?

Comment: If you meant the Canadian Broadcasting Corporation website (another news agency), that is cbc.ca, not cbc.com.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ok, I tested it and updated it with cbc.ca.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm being downvoted for "needs more debugging details". I don't know what other information is being expected. It's clear that the fetch should work normally, the error is 404, and the two lines to reproduce the error is literally shown.

Comment: For what it's worth, the problem does reproduce for me. I assume the WSJ is using some kind of anti-bot protection, although responding with a 404 in this case seems a bit... passive-aggressive? Not what I would have expected, at least. Anyway, try setting the user-agent?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It worked, thank you! Do you want to post your answer? Otherwise I will write up the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first import Request like this:

```
from urllib.request import **Request**, urlopen
```

and then pass your url and header to Request like below:

```
url = 'https://www.wsj.com/'
response_obj = urlopen(Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}))
print(response_obj)
```

I tested it now its working